# Can't set the higher half of ymm registers

Tags: x86-64, avx2

I'm trying to extend the word values from the lower half of the ymm0 register into the lower and higher half of it. When I execute the `vpunpcklwd` instruction, the higher half of the ymm0 register is left unchanged. This is the code line:

`vpunpcklwd ymm0, ymm0, ymm0`

Am I overseeing something? Could this be an OS bug or a CPU bug?
I'm using Windows 11 Pro on an Intel Core i5-10210U with Visual Studio 2019. I've tried to compile the code with the Visual C++ and Intel C++ compiler and to use a different destination register but nothing changes.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess this is a misunderstanding on your side, `vpunpcklwd` does: "Unpack and interleave 16-bit integers from the low half of each 128-bit lane in a and b, and store the results in dst.". So it does essentially two independent `punpcklwd xmm0,xmm0` on both lanes (=128bit halves) of `ymm0`. Maybe describe what you actually want (in pseudo code) to get a hint what instruction to use.

Comment: xmm0 contains a bitmask of all 0s or all 1s that's why I want to extend xmm0 with xmm0 into ymm0

Comment: So just `vinsertf128 ymm0, ymm0, xmm0, 1`? Or `vpmovsxbw ymm0, xmm0`?

Comment: Thank you. I've used vpmovsxwd ymm0, xmm0 since I want to extend words to dwords.

Comment: Problems with one instruction are basically never an OS or CPU bug.  When an instruction doesn't do what you thought it would, re-read the pseudocode in the manual carefully.  https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/punpcklbw:punpcklwd:punpckldq:punpcklqdq
Bugs in the manual are possible but AVX2 has been around long enough that most of them have been spotted by now.  (And that's not the case here.)

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I didn't take care to look at the pseudocode. I wasn't keeping in mind that vpunpcklwd performs unpacking separately on the lower and higher 128 bit lane.The pseudocode for the vpunpcklwd instruction doesn't tell anything about this bahavior. Do you assume by standard that instructions on ymm registers will operate on the higher and lower lane separately unless explicitly somehow pointed out in the documentation? vpmovsxwd on the other side performs signed extension across both 128 bit lanes.